# Jenkins SVN Plugin through Proxy

Tags: java, svn, jenkins, proxy, continuous-integration

I am having trouble setting up the Jenkins SVN plugin behind a proxy.

According to the docs:

```
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin
```

> *You can set the proxy in
>   C:/Users//AppData/Roaming/Subversion/servers (Windows)  or
>   ~/.subversion/servers (Linux)*

I have done this, I am on a unix box and have configured the ~/.subversion/servers correctly and can successfully SVN checkout directly on the command line from the box that Jenkins is running on.

When I try to checkout through SVN in Jenkins however, I get this error:

> Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn:
>   E170001: HTTP proxy authorization failed  at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:262)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:451)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:382)
>     ... 75 more

So the configurion in the servers file is working, but doesnt seem to be picked up in Jenkins.

I have also set the proxy details in the Manage plugins -> advanced page, and can successfully download and update plugins through Jenkins.

Is there something else I need to setup the SVN plugin not covered in the docs?

Jenkins is running on a Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to remove ~/.subversion directory and try to rebuild your project. It helps in some cases

Comment: The proxy configuration is defined here:  ~/.subversion/servers so if I remove that it wont be able to get the proxy config from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that proxy authorization failed. Is the Jenkins server running under the same user id that you did your command line test? If not does the server user id have access through the proxy? This system user will/may not be using  ~/.subversion/servers file that you configured.

Comment: It definitely reads the ~/.subversion/servers configuration file I have defined. I know this because I attached a remote debugger and stepped through the code and can see the correct proxy parameters being picked up. ie host,port,username and password. Seems to be a bug with svnkit, but I dont know if theres a workaround